# HTML5 geolocation marker movement and map update

Tags: html, geolocation

I am working on a location-based app for a school project and the following script paints the map with a new marker every time the GPS updates, leaving trails of markers. How do I make it so that whenever the GPS updates the map is displayed with the updated map marker positioned at the center of the map (which is like what all mobile map app does with the marker moving in accordance to user's movement)? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Geolocation default</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = null;

    const POSITION_OPTIONS = {enableHighAccuracy:true, maximumAge:30000, timeout:27000};

    function GetMap() {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), { credentials: 'ArqqdSR0U_ZzTkRh5W_3p0yukEEJ5X0L5QE9rg1CK1uyWgGz1n0Fi_-c2i2IfSN6' });
        GetLocation();
    }

    function GetLocation() {
        //check if location api supported
        if (!!navigator.geolocation) {

            //Update location
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(UpdateLocation,HandleErrors,POSITION_OPTIONS);
        }
    }

    function UpdateLocation(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        //move map to new location and zoom in
        map.setView({ center: { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude }, zoom: 16, mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial });

        var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude);

        var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc); 
        map.entities.push(pin);
    }

    function HandleErrors(error) {
        //handle geolocation errors and alert user
        switch (error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("user did not share geolocation data");
                break;

            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("could not detect current position");
                break;

            case error.TIMEOUT: alert("retrieving position timed out");
                break;

            default: alert("unknown error");
                break;
        }  
    }

</script>

</head>
<body onload="GetMap();" style="padding:0;margin:0;">

<div id="myMap" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best bet is to have some JavaScript code that forces your page to reload in a given interval. Here is some code to help you out:

```
var t = setTimeout("window.location.reload(true)",3000);
```

You would want to put the window.location.reload(true) in your update function and pass the update method into the setTimeout method, eg;

```
var t = setTimeout("UpdateLocation()",3000);
```

Then, you would call window.location.reload presumably after you have passed the users coordinates back to the server.

Hope this helps!